# hsla is visible in the browser as rgba

Tags: css, colors, rgba

I really like working with hsla color format.
hsla is visible in the browser as rgba.

How can i see which hsla values am i sending exactly (using devtools elements panel)?

[this indicates how to browser displays a linear-gradient i've given the body element, using rgba values instead of hsla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LMSQ.png)

Of course i can just use the rgba format but i find that much less intuitive and less productive. no one can really master hues with rgb syntax.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Colors can be defined in all three ways: rgba, HEX or hsla in chrome or safari. You can rotate through these 3 different sets by clicking on the color square right next to your color.

If you see the image, I have highlighted the square where you should click. Once you click on it you will see two arrows which you can use to toggle between different color formats.

Comment: Thank you, that does help alot. tough being so that those settings are changed dynamically and being animated it is not very conveneint and i would like to change the displayed options to show hsla only, if possible (it refreshes rapidly).

Comment: You are welcome. If your problem is resolved, please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: In what format it is shown in inspector depends on how the css is written. If your stylesheet is using hsla for animation then it will show hsla here. If you are using hex then it will show hex. and you can change the format if you wish. So, in your styles, write the animation using hsla values and not hex